No puedo acceder a la carpeta public en Codeigniter-4
Buen día,
Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, instale por primera vez el framework codeigniter-4, al intentar acceder a la carpeta public desde el localhost me sale "404 - File Not Found" en vez de redireccionarme al Home del Framework, he visto varios tutoriales en internet pero ninguno me funciono. 
Aquí se ve la carpeta public a la que quiero acceder.


Y aquí se ve el mensaje "404-File Not Found", lo curioso es que ese mensaje si esta establecido en el framework solo si no encuentra la pagina obviamente pero no me redirecciona a la pagina de bienvenida del codeigniter.
Cabe recalcar que en el php.ini del Xampp si tengo activo el "extension=intl" y "extension=mbstring",
Este es mi .htaccess de mi carpeta public.
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end

Este es el Routes en la configuración del framework.
<?php namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

// Load the system's routing file first, so that the app and ENVIRONMENT
// can override as needed.
if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php'))
{
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Router Setup
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

// We get a performance increase by specifying the default
// route since we don't have to scan directories.
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Additional Routing
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * There will often be times that you need additional routing and you
 * need it to be able to override any defaults in this file. Environment
 * based routes is one such time. require() additional route files here
 * to make that happen.
 *
 * You will have access to the $routes object within that file without
 * needing to reload it.
 */
if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php'))
{
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}



En un imagen solo se visualiza la carpeta public, esa es la única que tienes?


Necesitas cambiar tu RewriteBase en tu .htaccess por el nombre de tu subcarpeta (en este caso /portalReportesV1 )
Asegurarte de que en la configuración de Apache, para el directorio tengas habilitado AllowOverride All:


    
        Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    

